# Downgrade Android Packages

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio-2.3

I have taken a clone of the existing repo and installed the latest Android tools for my React Native project. Now the project is up and running on my system. But I have made changes to the following files without intending it.

**1) app/build.gradle :**

> -buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
>
> +buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

**2) android/ build.gradle**

> -classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
>
> +classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

**3)android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

> -distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
>
> +distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

**I want to undo/checkout these changes** (Probably might have to downgrade some of the tools). Need a safe way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong here?

Comment: If I keep these changes and push it back to the repo, everyone has to update their versions. So I better change the versions to match everyone's.

Comment: It so, Manually replace them as they were before.

Comment: There was nothing before. Did a fresh startup. I'd appreciate if you can suggest the way to downgrade these tools.

Comment: In your question you have already posted 3 changes which auto took place, right? You just have to edit them with your previous config. You can also use "local history" in Android studio, which will show you before and after changes.

Comment: Just altering the changes will not make the build work. The currently installed tools are not of that version. Kindly understand the problem. It is not as easy as reverting a git commit.